# Saving text into multiple files

Tags: r, save

How can I save the output data at each loop with the following filenames: "file01.txt", "file02.txt", ..
?
Here is the example of my R code:

```
data <- matrix(c(59, 50, 48, 62, 44, 34, 78, 59, 42, 67, 51, 45, 72, 64, 52), 
                 byrow=TRUE, ncol=3)
u <- c(33, 46, 53)
for (i in 1:length(u)){
           data[data<u[i]] <- NA  
           data <- data
           print(data)
}
           [,1] [,2] [,3]
      [1,]   59   50   48
      [2,]   62   44   34
      [3,]   78   59   42
      [4,]   67   51   45
      [5,]   72   64   52
           [,1] [,2] [,3]
      [1,]   59   50   48
      [2,]   62   NA   NA
      [3,]   78   59   NA
      [4,]   67   51   NA
      [5,]   72   64   52
           [,1] [,2] [,3]
      [1,]   59   NA   NA
      [2,]   62   NA   NA
      [3,]   78   59   NA
      [4,]   67   NA   NA
      [5,]   72   64   NA
```

Comment: You're also better off getting in the habit of using seq() vs. the colon operator.  E.g. seq(length(u)) instead of 1:length(u).  To see why, set the length of u to 0 and see how each behaves.  E.g. u <- c()

Answer (score 5):

Create a character variable with the filename in it, and use `write.table()`.

```
for(i in 1:length(u)) {
  ...
  filename = paste("file", i, ".txt", sep="")
  write.table(data, filename)
}
```

Comment: Good answer. If you use: filename = paste("file", sprintf("%02d", i), ".txt", sep=""), then you will get "file01", "file02"... instead of "file1", "file2".